# How Can I Use Open-jdk On Android Phone Just Like Jvdriod app

Tags: segmentation-fault, java-11

Please i need your help i am unable to use open-jdk on my Terminal (Not Termux) android app i know is possible because jvdroid has it custom jdk which i will like to have idea on how it

i have download the open-jdk from all site but they showing cant open directory or Unsatisfied link error. I have try using jvdroid apk open-jdk but it show Segmentation Fault which confused me cause when i use it on termux it worked well but when i use it in my terminal or any other terminal like an sole or ATE i get Segmentation Fault but the jvdroid open-jdk works well for termux but not for me i thinking is their anything that jvdroid and termux has in common   please help me fix this problem